# Integral involving log(-log(x))

Tags: calculus

Do you have any ideas of how to solve the following integral
$$
\int_0^1 \log(-\log(x))m(1-x)^{m-1}dx
$$
or relate it to a special function?

Comment: I would start by letting $x=e^{-t}$.

Comment: Equivalent to $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(m+1)(\ln(s)+\gamma)\Gamma(s+1)(\psi(s+1)-\psi(m+s+1))}{\Gamma(m+s+1)}\, ds$. Where $\psi$ is the digamma function. I would be very surprised if this has a closed-form.

Comment: With CAS help. If: $m>0$ and $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ then: $$\int_0^1 \log (-\log (x)) m (1-x)^{m-1} \, dx=-\frac{\gamma  \Gamma (1+m)}{m \Gamma (m)}-\Gamma (1+m) \sum _{\alpha =0}^{m-1}
   \frac{(-1)^{\alpha } \log (1+\alpha )}{\Gamma (m-\alpha ) \Gamma (2+\alpha )}$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk so, eventually, the term is equal to $-\gamma -\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (-1)^j \binom{m}{j+1} * \log(1+j)$. Do you have an idea of the limit behaviour of the sum as $m\to \infty$?

Comment: If $m\to \infty$ sum is divergent.